# Distribution of number of rolls yielding an even number conditioned on the number of rolls until 6 is rolled.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> A fair 6-sided die is rolled repeatedly until 6 is rolled. Let $Y$ be the number of rolls, and let $X$ be the number of rolls that yielded an even number. Find the distribution of $(X|Y)$.

**My attempt:**
With each roll the probability to get a 6 is $\frac{1}{6}$, so Y is $Geo(\frac{1}{6})$. $Supp(x) = \mathbb N$, so let $n \in \mathbb N$. By total probability we have:
$\mathbb P(X=n|Y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P(X=n|Y=k) \mathbb P(Y=k)$.
If $Y=k$, then on 6 was rolled only on the k-th roll. So if there were $k$ rolls and $n$ of them were even, then in the first $k-1$ rolls there were $n-1$ rolls that yielded an even number that isn't 6. So in those $n-1$ rolls the probability to roll an even number is $\frac{2}{5}$.

So here's my confusion - it seems to me that $(X=n|Y=k)$ is $Bin(n-1, \frac{2}{5})$. But I still think according to total probability we have to sum over all possible $k$ values. If we do that we get:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P(X=n|Y=k) \mathbb P(Y=k) = $$
$$ \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mathbb P(X=n|Y=k) \mathbb P(Y=k) = $$
$$ \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{k-n}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) = $$
$$ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1} $$

When the first equality is true since if $k<n$, meaning there were total $k$ rolls, there can't be $n>k$ rolls.

Now I'm not sure if this is even correct and if this is the right way to go.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Summing over $k$ would give you $\mathbb P(X=n)$ rather than $\mathbb P(X=n \mid Y=k)$

Comment: Oh that's true. So is it $Bin(n-1, \frac{2}{5})$? I'm not sure how to show that rigorously though.

Comment: So for example, $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid Y) = \left(\frac25\right)^{Y-1}$ while $\mathbb P(X=1) = \frac13$ (assuming you count the $6$ roll as even rather than ignoring it).  More generally it seems $\mathbb P(X=n) = \frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n}$ but that is not the original question

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb P(X=1 | Y) = \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{Y-1}$? Since it's the probability to roll an odd result $Y-1$ times.

Comment: Yes I did intend  $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid Y) = \left(\frac35\right)^{Y-1}$ - sorry

Comment: It might be easier to approach it directly? IE If $Y = y$, what is the probability that $ X = 0, 1, \ldots, y, y+1 \ldots$?

Comment: That was my line of thinking and that's why I used the total probability law. But again I got the calculation above which results in $\mathbb P (X=n)$. Logically I think it's a binomial distribution ($n-1$ successes (getting an even result) out of $k-1$ trials ($k-1$ rolls not counting the last one that yields 6). So how do you show this (if it is indeed true)?

Answer (score 1):

The event $\ \{Y=n\}\cap\{X=m\}\ $ occurs if and only if the  $\ n^\text{th}\ $ roll is a $\ 6\ $ and there are exactly $\ m-1\ $ even rolls not equal to $\ 6\ $ , and $\ n-m\ $ odd rolls preceding the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ roll. There exist $\ {n-1\choose m-1}\ $ such sequences, all with the same probability, $\ \frac{1}{3^{m-1}2^{n-m}6}=\frac{1}{3^m2^{n+1-m}}\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
P(Y=n, X=m)&=\cases{{n-1\choose m-1}\frac{1}{3^m2^{n+1-m}}&if$\ 1\le m\le n$\\0&otherwise}\\
P(Y=n)&=\frac{5^{n-1}}{6^n}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
P(X=m\,|\,Y=n\,)&=\frac{P(Y=n, X=m)}{P(Y=n)}\\
&=\cases{{n-1\choose m-1}\frac{3^{n-m}2^{m-1}}{5^{n-1}}&if$\ 1\le m\le n$\\0&otherwise.}
\end{align}
That is,
$$
P(X=m\,|\,Y)=\cases{{Y-1\choose m-1}\frac{3^{Y-m}2^{m-1}}{5^{Y-1}}&if$\ 1\le m\le Y$\\0&otherwise.}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate on how you calculated $\mathbb P(Y=n, X=m)$?

Comment: Now added.  Even after I thought I had corrected my original exponents they were still off by $1$, so it's a good thing you asked for the derivation.